# Should I create a database with only 1 table or its preferible to use a javascript object like database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The information that I want to save of my web page clients can be put in only 1 sql table, but maybe its better to use a javascript object like database no? I'm not sure if the javascript object will support the clients traffic in my CRUD web page. I'm using node js with express for the server :)

Comment: Please provide either some code that you've tried or at least some sort of data structure so we have an idea on how we can help guide you. And as always, it depends :)

Comment: What do you mean by javascript object? Store json in a file?

Comment: Oh yeah, a simple object like: var database = { id: 0, name: "mark", age: 19 }

Comment: Consider using mongoose/mongo for extensibility, but if you are making a simple website, just presisting a single JSON file to disk should be simple enough, though I advise against it

Comment: Or I should create a database with only 1 table for save that information?, I have not started with the code, I want to know what is the best option for this :)

Comment: For limited use case with low volume it might be ok if you load from file at startup and keep it in memory, and you don't expect concurrent writes. But if the object grows in volume and you want to query, say, by name, you would need to have indexes (maps) for reasonable performances.

Comment: Oh okok, I understand, but for example with an INSERT action, ¿Can the javacript object support concurrent writes?

Comment: No problem for in-memory operations, JS is on a single thread so it's fine. Problems may arise if you need to scale the infrastructure (like having multiple processes writing to the same file)

Comment: All users are going to modify the same javascript object in certains moment, ¿Am going to have problems with that? :o